# How to group by within range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

let's say I have a dataframe with multiple features x1,x2,x3,x4. I want to cluster every records that have exact the same values in x1, and difference within .15 in x2 and x3, and difference within .2 in x4.

I am aware that the exact features we can use `df.groupby()` and choose the subsequent to be x1. However, how can I cluster with not exact values in x2, x3, and x4?

EDIT:
Here's an example of the data set:

```
x1  x2       x3   x4
4   0.30    .5    1
4   0.50    .65   2
3   1.00    3     3
3   1.15    3.15  3.2
3   1.12    3.1  3.4
```

As shown I want every group to have the same x1 so I will begin with `groupby('x1)`. Then I want to check if x2, and x3 within difference .15, we will find that the first and second row have difference more than .15 --> it's (.5-.3) thus I will not group these two rows together instead each row will be in a group alone. Then I will check the group that have x1=3, we will check we will find that all x2 values and x3 values are within range .15. However, we will find in x4, difference .4 between the first and the last element. Thus we will group this the second and the last element together (there's difference .2 between 3.2 and 3.4)and the first element alone because there's difference more than.2 (.4 between 3 and 3.4)

Comment: Please, do share data and your own attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: use pd.cut - post sample data for more specific answers please

Comment: Thank you for your comment I added the data.
I think that pd.cut assumes that I know the ranges of the values, however I know the difference that is allowed to be within the coloum of each group